# How to display data stored in core data in a table view?

Tags: iphone, orbeon

I have developed a core data model for my application. I need to display the saved data into a table view. For my app I have selected split view controller. I am writing down my codes below. Please help me in this regard and write me the code that needs to be added. This is very important as my continuation in my company depends on this.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "AddViewController.h"
#import "EmployeeDetailsAppDelegate.h"

/*
 This template does not ensure user interface consistency during editing operations in the table view. You must implement appropriate methods to provide the user experience you require.
 */

@interface RootViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end



@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize detailViewController, fetchedResultsController, managedObjectContext, results, empName;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    results = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [results setObject:empName.text forKey:@"EmployeeName"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


/*
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
 */
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
 */
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
 */

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Ensure that the view controller supports rotation and that the split view can therefore show in both portrait and landscape.    
    return YES;
}


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"EmployeeName"] description];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Add a new object

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {

    AddViewController *add = [[AddViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    add.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;

    [self presentModalViewController:add animated:YES];
    [add release];  
}   


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"EmployeeName"] description];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete the managed object.
        NSManagedObject *objectToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (self.detailViewController.detailItem == objectToDelete) {
            self.detailViewController.detailItem = nil;
        }

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:objectToDelete];

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }   
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // The table view should not be re-orderable.
    return NO;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Set the detail item in the detail view controller.
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = selectedObject;    
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"EmployeeName" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}    


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller delegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [detailViewController release];
    [fetchedResultsController release];
    [managedObjectContext release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end



//
//  AddViewController.m
//  EmployeeDetails
//
//  Created by Dipanjan on 15/02/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AddViewController.h"
#import "EmployeeDetailsAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"


@implementation AddViewController

@synthesize empName;
@synthesize empID;
@synthesize empDepartment;
@synthesize backButton;

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

-(void)saveDetails{

    EmployeeDetailsAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *newDetails;

    newDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newDetails setValue:empID.text forKey:@"EmployeeID"];
    [newDetails setValue:empName.text forKey:@"EmployeeName"];
    [newDetails setValue:empDepartment.text forKey:@"EmployeeDepartment"];

    empID.text = @"";
    empName.text = @"";
    empDepartment.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"%@........----->>>...", newDetails);

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

-(void)findDetails {

    EmployeeDetailsAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Details" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(EmployeeName = %@)", empName.text];

    [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


    if ([objects count] == 0) {
    }
    else {
        matches = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
        empID.text = [matches valueForKey:@"EmployeeID"];
        empDepartment.text = [matches valueForKey:@"EmployeeDepartment"];
        }

    [request release];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {

    self.empName = nil;
    self.empID = nil;
    self.empDepartment = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [empID release];
    [empName release];
    [empDepartment release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Please let me know the answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dipanjan there is a core data tutorial in the devlopers document of X-Code and here it is [**coreDataBooks**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) and its a best one try to take help from there in order to display the data in `UITableView` have a look at `NSFetchedResultsController` method.

http://www.bukisa.com/articles/180100_iphone-core-data-tutorial-part-1

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have gone through the CoreDataBooks and have completed my app too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the data from the data using NSFetchResult. I guess you are doing it in the `findDetails` method, but where are you calling that method? You need to call that method to fetch the data, and then try to reload the table